# using foreign keys with mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I have a forgiven key issue using MySQL. I have a studies table and a samples table. Users can add studies and also add samples. every sample belongs to a study, but studies can have many samples. So theres a one to many relationship with studies and samples. I need to set up a foreign key in the samples table so that whenever a new sample is created it can be referenced by its parent study. I set up a foreign key in the sample table with this script below, but whenever I add a new sample it leaves the study_id column empty. I’m new using foreign keys so any examples would be great. Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE `studies` (
    `study_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `study_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` tinytext,
    `reads` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `created_at` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`study_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `samples` (
    `sample_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `study_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `sample_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`sample_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`study_id`)
    REFERENCES `studies` (`study_id`)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: How do you try to add a sample to the table?

Comment: just a simple 'insert into 'samples' set ? and than I pass the values. So I'm not sure how the DB is suppose know what study each sample is referenced too.. thats the real problem I suppose

Comment: do I have to do some type of get request before I even try to query the DB with an 'insert'.. basically get the study ID and than re-save it into the samples table? seems like there should be a better way

Comment: You have to provide the study id in your insert. The foreign key only ensures that the study id you enter must exist in the study table, it cannot figure out the falue for you.